# $_POST[] without isset works fine but...

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am new to php and mysql in general. but i have a problem Here is my problem:

I am trying to Insert data into database using forms. 
but when i do, it returns 1 in username password columns.

Here is my Index.php:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname= 'akar';
$user = 'akar';
$pass = 'raparen';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);

$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);



    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,password)  VALUES(:username,:password)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':username'=> $username,
        ':password'=> $password
    ));

?>
```

Here is my form:

```
<form action='index.php' method='post'>

<input type='text' placeholder='Enter Username here!' name='username' />
<input type='password' placeholder='Enter Password here!' name='password' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
```

When i do this:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

It Works fine but when i do this:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
```

It inserts 1 in the database, and not the text in the input.

Sorry if i organize anything, i am newbie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isset()` returns a boolean value that is the result of the variable(s) being checked being set or not. It is not to be used to get values from a variable.

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);
```

should be:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Or, if you want to assign a default value if those variables are not set, you would do it this way:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
```

Comment: What index does it claim as undefined?

Answer (score 4):

That's because [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) returns `true` if the var exists and has value other than NULL, and returns false otherwise.  "Return Values" from the doc:

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE
>   otherwise.

So by doing `$username = isset($_POST['username']);`, you are assigning the return value of `isset` to `$username` which is what is going to get stored in your database.

What you should be doing is:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
}
```

So that you assign the value of `$_POST['username']` only if `$_POST['username']` is set.

Comment: That last snippet will leave them with an undefined variable error in their query.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  $statement = $pdo->prepare( $query);

  $statement->bindValue( “:username”, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $statement->bindValue( “:password”, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR );

  $statement->execute();
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
echo “Query failed: “ . $e->getMessage();
}
```